# Assigning value to local variable inside subscribe() function Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a variable:

`isLoading = true;`

in my component, which updated the visibility of loader animation. I make this value to false while I subscribe to a service in `ngOnInit()` lifecycle hook.

`ngOnInit(){service.subscribe(data => {isLoading = false;});}`

`ngAfterViewInit(){if(isLoading == false){//do something}}`

The action/function inside of my `ngAfterViewInit()` is dependent on wether the data is loaded or not. But when I `console.log` the isLoading variable inside of `ngAfterViewInit()` it is still true, the value become false somewhere later.

How to handle this, I need to set the isLoading to false when my data is loading?

Comment: Shouldn't you just `//do something` when the `event` that call the `subscriber()` triggers ?, that would help you on debugging